# Question about proof particular L'Hospital's case

Tags: calculus, limits

My brain is not exactly understanding a particular proof for the L'Hospital's case when $x$ goes to infinity. The author considers $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where he subs $t=1/x$ It continues  $\lim\limits_{t\to0+}\frac{f(1/t)}{g(1/t)}$ on which he then applies L'Hospital's Rule. I can see what happens then, ultimately arriving at the term $\lim\limits_{t\to0+}\frac{f'(1/t)}{g'(1/t)}$ which is$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ 
Now let's look at an example: $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{x^2+x}{x^2+1}$ When I perform the sub $t=1/x$ it comes down to $\lim\limits_{t\to0+}\frac{1/t^2+1/t}{1/t^2+1}$ which is $\lim\limits_{t\to0+}\frac{1+t}{1+t^2}$ after multiplying through by $t^2$ Now how can you apply L'Hospital's Rule here? This limit exists by simply "putting" $t=0$ to find $1$. Why is the author applying l"hospital's Rule in the proof?
If anybody can shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated as I am obviously missing something fundamental here. Thanks

Comment: The proof doesn't apply L'Hospital to $\frac{t^2f(1/t)}{t^2g(1/t)}$, it applies it to $\frac{f(1/t)}{g(1/t)}$. So, if you want to continue with L'Hospital, don't multiply by $t^2$. Remember that L'Hospital being applicable doesn't mean that it leads to the computation of the limit. In fact, applying L'Hospital to $\frac{1/t^2+1/t}{1/t^2+1}$ doesn't lead directly to the computation of the limit.

Comment: But $f(1/t)$ and $g(1/t)$ means that $x$ is replaced by $1/t$ That does not yield a zero over zero situation. Why can you apply the Rule on $\lim\limits_{t\to0+}\frac{1/t^2+1/t}{1/t^2+1}$ ?

Comment: It doesn't, it leads to the same type of indeterminate form as it was before $\infty/\infty$. It only changes where the limit is taken.

Comment: But the prove is about to show that L'Hospital can be used for inf over inf. If it is the same indeterminate form after the substitution, what argument can be used to apply the Rule, which is what the author does...

Comment: If the author is changing $x$ by $1/t$ the goal is just to change the limit from $x\to\infty$ to $t\to0$. If you want to change the indeterminate form from $\infty/\infty$ to $0/0$ then change $f(x)/g(x)$ to $\frac{1/f(x)}{1/g(x)}$.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, but it didn't work out, or at least I couldn't make it work. My point is, that if the author does the substitution, that a new expression is obtained for which the Rule would apply. I fail to recognize that.

Comment: I don't know. There are many proofs of L'Hospital. I don't know what path they are taking. Can you include the proof in your question?

Comment: I did, I only skipped the step where the author applied the derivative on $f(1/t)$ and $g(1/t)$ which involves chain rule. In both cases it produces $-1/t^2$ and so that cancels. The proof is mentioned in Stewart Calculus Chapter 6

Comment: Ha! That book. Let me take a look. I wouldn't be impressed if he completely botches or fakes a proof. Worst Calculus book I have ever been forced to teach from. Chapter 6? What edition is that?

Comment: I looked at it. He only proves the case $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$, in the cases $a$ finite and $a=\infty$. The proof of the case $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\infty$ is not there. That book is super heavy, extremely expensive, and a complete garbage. Many proofs there are incomplete, or wrong. Many of the techniques are also incomplete or misguide the student through paths that don't help to solve other problems.

Comment: My advice: Use some other book to study, and if you need Stewart's to use in class, just download it.

Comment: Ok,will look into it thanks (PS, it is the 7th edition)

Comment: @Pp.. I agree that the proof is "strange" to say the least. Either he skips a lot in that proof or it is something else. We use the book because of the fine chronological build up and the plenty of exercises available. For explanations and proofs I very often cite other resources...

Comment: It is just incomplete. He never proves all the cases. Just as he never shows how to *integrate all simple fractions*, or how to *compute slant asymptotes*.

Comment: You are so right about that slant asymptotes thing. That's no where in the book. And he keeps stating that the tangent half angle formula for integration is from Weierstrass, which is also not true....

Comment: He does defines slant/oblique asymptotes, but only shows how to compute them for rational functions using long division, while the general formula is as simple as the definition.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it seems that I haven't understood your doubts quite well.

Comment: @AméricoTavares. Ok, here is something that might address my concern. Can you refer me to a link that proves the validity for Hospital's rule for the infinity over infinity situation when x goes to infinity?

Comment: @Pp.. Yes, but $y=\sqrt{x^2-4x}$ also has slant asymptotes. In my view a good example, but not in Stewart.